# Is there a way to automatically disable the UAC each time Windows 7 boots (I'm an administrator)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, uac, group-policy

At work, we have a group policy (I think it is a group policy, correct me if I use the wrong term!) that automatically resets the UAC to "`Default`" every two days or so.

I'm administrator on the computer and I have the rights to disable the UAC. For some reasons (please no discussion about this...) I want the UAC to *always* be disabled.

Is there a way to set up a scheduled task or something to automatically disable the UAC each time the computer boots?

Comment: If you are a domain Administrator you should be able to adjust the configuration to make this possible.  If you are not then its not possible since you are not an Administrator on the domain.

Comment: @Ramhound Even if I'm an administrator on the machine and I *can* disable the UAC manually?

Comment: It is not a best way to override the central GPO settings, but if you have local administrator rights, the you can change and retain UAV settings by applying it in Local Group Policy. The GPO settings processed in the following order. 1. Local GPO, 2. Sites, 3. Domain GPO, 4. OU policy. Please take a look at the following URL to apply the Local group policy settings and apply it on your machine. Hope this helps.

Comment: @vembutech I think you forgot the URL! :-) And what should I change in the Local Group Policy to disable the UAC?

Comment: Got it, I'll try it tomorrow! http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/disable-uac-for-windows-servers-through-group-policy/

Comment: I don't have the rights to change those security Local group policies... Damn!